# In iMacros for Firefox, the loop can still run as I expect when error occurs?

Tags: firefox, loops, error-handling, imacros

pls see below code:

"123.iim"

```
VERSION BUILD=8510617 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:firstname CONTENT=ABC
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:lastname CONTENT=LDEF
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:email CONTENT=abcdef@gmail.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:choice
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LI ATTR=TXT:F
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:like CONTENT=swimming
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:hate CONTENT=hiking
```

In iMacros for Firefox, I want to press "play (loop)" from 1 to 10 to make a loop on a macro called "123.iim". If I got an error at line 6. , the macro will stop running and the loop stops.

I know that I can add a command: SET !ERRORIGNORE YES to ignore the error and keep running the macro and loop.

```
VERSION BUILD=8510617 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:firstname CONTENT=ABC
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:lastname CONTENT=LDEF
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:email CONTENT=abcdef@gmail.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:choice
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LI ATTR=TXT:F
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:like CONTENT=swimming
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:hate CONTENT=hiking
```

However, this command will run each lines after the error, that is, error on line 7, it will continue to run line 8, 9 & 10.
I do not want that.
What I want is that the macro run line 1-6, error occurs at line 7, then the loop will start at line 1 (rather than continue to run line 8, 9 & 10).

If at a time, no error occurs at line 7 now, the loop will run from line 1 to line 10.

how can I do?

I am not sure if I present well, but I hope someone can do me a favor urgently. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This kind of complicated logic can not be done using regular imacros script. you need to run it from javascript or vbs script which will handle all logic conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using !ERRORIGNORE with !TIMEOUT_STEP (for certain steps). This will make it quickly jump to the next step in case of an error. Normally it waits for 6 seconds, that's 10% of the time what is set in Timeout Limit under iMacros options.

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0

http://wiki.imacros.net/!ERRORIGNORE

http://wiki.imacros.net/!TIMEOUT_STEP

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
VERSION BUILD=8510617 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:firstname CONTENT=ABC
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:lastname CONTENT=LDEF
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:email CONTENT=abcdef@gmail.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:choice
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LI ATTR=TXT:F
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:like CONTENT=swimming
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:hate CONTENT=hiking
```

This way the macro will ignore errors but after !ERRORIGNORE NO it will break from loop if error occurs. I suggest using JavaScript scripting. It has much better error handling.